# Macro with two arguments

Tags: macros

I want to define a macro that takes two inputs

```
\Make{a}{b~\theint}
```

where the macro defined by

````
```
\newcounter{int}
\newcommand{\Make}[2][]{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\par\medskip{
\textbf{\small #2 -- Fall 2020} \par
    \setcounter{int}{1}   
    \loop
    \input{#1}
  \newpage
 \addtocounter{int}{1}\ifnum\value{int}<8
    \repeat
 } \rmfamily}{\medskip}
```
````

but I'm getting the error that the file in the input command is not found

Comment: `~` is a non-breaking space (a command to produce a space in the PDF) and it doesn't work as a “general string”.  Use `{b \theint}` instead

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You sure that's the issue? I'd rather say that the macro is defined to take one optional parameter (the file name) which defaults to empty...

Comment: @campa Ah, right, ignore me.  (regardless, a `b~\theint` wouldn't work in the file name as seems to be the intent here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\Make` is defined to take two arguments, the first of which is optional, since it has the following structure:

```
\newcommand{\Make}[2][]{%
  % <your definition>
}
```

As such, calling it with two mandatory arguments `\Make{<a>}{<b>}` will effectively ignore `<b>` as part of `\Make`, and assign `#1` (the optional argument) an empty/blank value and `#2` = `<a>`. Change your definition to the following:

```
\newcommand{\Make}[2]{%
  % <your definition>
}
```

Also note the use of `%` here. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)